# Hibernate JPA persistence - How to obtain new entity identifier after insert / save / merge

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am quite new to Hibernate / JPA persistence and am trying to find how to obtain the ID of an inserted record in the database via the new object I create to do so.

I am using Hibernate 4.0.4 and am utilising hibernates session API as opposed to the EntityManager.

### User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private int id;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Column(name = "firstName", nullable = false)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setHeroes(List<Hero> heroes) {
        this.heroes = heroes;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

### Execution code - attempt 1

```
User user = new User();
user.setEmail((String) arg.get("email"));
user.setFirstName((String) arg.get("firstName"));
user.setLastName((String) arg.get("lastName"));
user.setPassword(Password.getSaltedHash((String) arg.get("password")));
Transaction tx = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction(); //committed later on...
int id = (Integer) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user); //This always returns 0 even though inserted rows in database have IDs as expected
```

### Execution code - attempt 2

```
//Same as before for defining user...

Transaction tx = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction(); //commited later on...
user = (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(user);
int id = user.getId(); //This also always returns 0 even though the rows are being inserted into the database as expected
```

So my question is:

How can I successfully persist the user object to the database and obtain the ID of the record through that user object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different kind of id columns. I suppose you want to get generated values, check out the different options of the `@GeneratedValue` annotation in combination with `@Id`.

As far as I know `GenerationType.AUTO` is able to auto-update your id field after storing it in the database. But you probably have to call a "flush()" before using the id-getter.

My best practice is to try to not depend on the technical Id of an object. If you need it for relations between objects, than you should definitely prefer to use `@OneToMany`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can confirm that by simply adding the annotation @GeneratedValue to the ID getter now returns the correct IDs in both attempts mentioned in my question. So simple but yet seemed so difficult for me to find appropriate literature.

Comment: And yes I agree with you that it is best for me to depend on the objects themselves between entity relationships, and that I do, but in this case I needed the ID for output as JSON to the front end.